# Can I use Pixmap Engine in GTK3 theme?

Tags: css, themes, gtk3, pixmap

Can I use the "pixmap" engine in GTK3 ".CSS" files? If so, how? I made a theme that I was pretty happy with, but was for a gnome 2 desktop. It used the pixmap engine to call on images saved in a folder to make buttons and text boxes. These images would be to hard for me to write out into a .CSS file.

Answer (score 3):

No, GTK 2 and GTK 3 theme engines are not compatible. However, you can easily include images into your CSS file using `url('my/path/to/image.png')`.